# Exporting rasterVis plot without border

Tags: r, lattice, r-raster, removing-whitespace, rastervis

I am trying to export rasters from the rasterViz package as jpg or png. I am struggling to:

- completely trim white border
- keep transparency for NAs

So far:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

# Toy Data
m <-  matrix(seq(0,100,length.out=15000),150,100)
r <- raster(m, xmn=0,ymn=0,xmx=nrow(m),ymx=ncol(m))

jpeg(file = "test.jpg", bg = "transparent", height=nrow(r), width=ncol(r))

levelplot(t(r), contour=T, margin=F, scales = list(draw=FALSE), colorkey=NULL,
 par.settings = list(axis.line = list(line=0), mar=c(0,0,0,0), omi=c(0,0,0,0), 
                          xaxt='n', yaxt='n', bg='transparent'))
dev.off()
```

...still has a white border and transparency isn't working (for the border at least). I'm also a little confused about needing to transpose the raster to plot.

For context; I need to preserve the aspect ratio and exactly trim to the extends so that I can use the images as map tiles elsewhere. It isn't feasible to do manual post processing.

Answer (score 1):

Only [png()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html) supports transparent backgrounds.

```
png(file = "test.png", bg = "transparent", height=nrow(r), width=ncol(r))
```

> png supports transparent backgrounds: use bg = "transparent". (Not all
>   PNG viewers render files with transparency correctly.) When
>   transparency is in use in the type = "Xlib" variant a very light grey
>   is used as the background and so appears as transparent if used in the
>   plot. This allows opaque white to be used, as in the example. The type
>   = "cairo", type = "cairo-png" and type = "quartz" variants allow semi-transparent colours, including on a transparent or
>   semi-transparent background.